# How to retrive an object name from an array if I have index number in objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have an array by all the objects. I don't know which index contain which object. When I use this array I just use index number. How to find name of object at that index?

```
NSString *extension = @"png";
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *contents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];  
    NSMutableArray *pngFiles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: [contents count]];

NSString *filename;
for (filename in contents)

{
    if ([[filename pathExtension] isEqualToString:extension]) 
    {
        [pngFiles addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename]]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to hold the folder listing using a dictionary instead.  You don't say what you are trying to do with the folder listing?

Comment: Please, paste here your current code.

Comment: Some times I need to delete some file at that's folder, when I need to know that's file name. Without correct name of that's file I couldn't delete that file.

Comment: do you what type of object it may have... you may be knowing the type of classes u have used.. from that u can recognize each object in array is of kind of class

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an array use a dictionary. So you can save that image name and image

```
[pngFiles setObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename]] forKey:filename];
```